# How to insert systimestamp in oracle sql developer?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

1. I click timestamp column for edit.
2. Double click edit mark of the cell and it pop up edit value tab.
3. And i click Now button for current system time to insert.

But i didnt get current time, I want to know how to get this i Oracle sql developer tool.

And how to export insert script with SYSTIMSTAMP keyword for required column?

Comment: if you didn't get the current time, what time did you get?

Comment: Could you tell , where do you actually trying to update the timestamp ? how you select the data and where ?

Comment: @thatjeffsmith An getting 6.30 hours less than current time. Can we insert default time or current time?

Comment: Why not use current_timestamp in update statement instead of manual edit.

Comment: it's probably showing you client vs db time - which won't always be the same

Comment: @thatjeffsmith Actually client and db time are same..but i different timing..its that i have to configure anything in sql ddveloper

Comment: we need more info, please add details to your question, your os details, your db details including timeszones in each, plus show us what you did and what you got